# Consider synonymizing [shocks] to [suspension]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Unless [shocks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shocks) is meant as a special case for [suspension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspension), I think they could be merged.

Happy to listen to counter-arguments.

Answer (score 2):

They're not synonymous because in bike parlance, "shock" typically refers to the rear/frame-mounted suspension component only. It would be reasonable to have [shocks], [suspension], and something like [suspension-forks]. The argument could be made that since the forks one doesn't exist, a specific shock tag probably shouldn't either. I would err more towards adding it than taking away [shocks]. It's true that being in the middle as it is now is the worst option.

Comment: I agree with this and would add that, in theory, [tag]suspension[/tag] could be used to discuss the kinematics of a rear linkage independent of the shock that is used.

Comment: @PaulH Yeah, reducing it all to [suspension] is probably fine too. I think having both a shocks and forks tag would be helpful for mechanical questions, so that's my bias over going more minimalist.

Comment: You could just make explicit tags for [rear-suspension] and [front-suspension], and decide whether to keep a generic [suspension] or not. Then alias [shocks] to the best candidate or denylist it and make people choose.